# What will happen to their properties/processions when an Indian citizen opts for foreign nationality?

Tags: citizenship, indian-citizens

**Scenario:**

An Indian citizen with family decides to settle in abroad (any country). Soon they receive an option to apply for the host country's citizenship. Now what will happen to their India-based properties/processions if they get foreign citizenship?

Comment: This is difficult to answer. The bureaucracy regarding property is so cluttered and inefficent that even for citizens living in India, it's impossible for simple transfers of possesion to take place within years of time. For non-resident Indians, it almost certainly is atleast as complex, especially when considering properties that only Indian citizens are allowed to own. Things are improving and defnitely have improved in recent years, but I still wouldn't count on any quick action by the government. If that property is indeed in your name, it could stay that way for the next century.

Comment: Yes, that's what I first thought.